Matthew 7:21-27, how does 'working of lawlessness' (v. 23) relate semantically to 'building on sand' (v. 26) and what's the exegetical significance?
Matthew 7:21-23 and Matthew 7:24-27 can be considered a cohesive unit semantically, as they both emphasize the importance of true discipleship and obedience to Jesus' teachings rather than mere verbal profession or external appearances. Semantically, does ἀνομία ('lawlessness') imply a complete disregard for the law, or could it also refer to a superficial adherence—where individuals follow the law outwardly but lack the genuine spirit of faith and love?
Text: (NET)

Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter into the kingdom
of heaven – only the one who does the will of my Father in heaven.
On that day, many will say to me, ‘Lord, Lord, didn’t we prophesy in
your name, and in your name cast out demons and do many powerful
deeds?’ 2Then I will declare to them, ‘I never knew you. Go away from
me, you lawbreakers!’(Matt 7:21-23)
“Everyone who hears these words of mine and does them is like a wise
man who built his house on rock. The rain fell, the flood came, and
the winds beat against that house, but it did not collapse because it
had been founded on rock. Everyone who hears these words of mine and
does not do them is like a foolish man who built his house on sand.
The rain fell, the flood came, and the winds beat against that
house, and it collapsed; it was utterly destroyed! (vv.24-27).


The closing verses of what is called "The Sermon on the Mount" certainly show there is a connection between Jesus' warning about professed believers who actually work  lawlessness, and the fool who suffers great loss by building on sand. That is due to the concluding sentence Matthew put at the end of this long sermon:

"And it came to pass, when Jesus had ended these sayings, the people
were astonished at his doctrine, for he taught them as one having
authority, and not as the scribes." Matthew 7:28-29 A.V. [My italics]

The ultimate lesson (what foundation to build upon) is therefore linked to the pen-ultimate illustration of those who produce 'bad fruit' and suffer eternal loss.
Of note is that both groups of people appear to be believers. Yet the ones claiming to have done great works in Christ's name are called false prophets who are inwardly 'ravening wolves' that mix with believers. See verses 13-16. What they take to be evidence of their 'good fruit' is deceptive. Jesus says they are workers of lawlessness.
However, to succeed as one in the midst of God's people as a prophet, requires keeping God's law to the extent that others are fooled by that. They cannot be totally lawless, otherwise nobody could be fooled by them. They appear to be in harmony with God's law. What they do, that is seen by others, appears to be not merely commendable, but miraculous!
As for the foolish builders, well, they are in an illustration about what identifies those who obey Jesus, and those who do not. To disobey Jesus is lawlessness. Might as well build a house on sand.
Those who obey Jesus' commands are wise builders whose obedience to Christ will ensure they do not suffer loss when a great time of testing of their work suddenly comes.
The two illustrations make different, yet crucially related points. First,  appearing to do good things in the congregation of God's people may be exposed on the Day of Judgment as actually working lawlessness, for what was done was not according to the will of God. To do the will of God is obedience to the will of God. To do one's own will by godless means is actually to go against the will (law, or command) of God. Secondly, those workers whose works resulted from disregarding what they knew Jesus had commanded say will see their works destroyed.
In both cases, both groups will be unable to defend their works. The first group claimed to be doing great things in Christ's name, thus admitting to claiming to be upholding the name of Christ in what they did. The second group chose to disregard what they knew Jesus required. Whereas one lot were false prophets, the others were fools. But both are equally culpable. Both will see their works exposed and amount to nothing in God's sight. Both committed great sin.
And this is where 1 John chapter 3 helpfully details how this links with sin, which is lawlessness. It need not be a total disregard for all law. Not by any manner of means! But whenever the will of God is disregarded, that is sin, and whenever the commands of Christ are disregarded, that is sin. That sin will result in loss and ruin. John's epistle shows that

"Whoever commiteth sin transgresseth also the law; for sin is the
transgression of the law... Whoever abideth in him [Christ] sinneth
not: whosoever sinneth hath not seen him, neither known him." 1 John
3:4-6 A.V.

To condense all this to one crucial point: Individual professed Christians may follow the law outwardly but lack the genuine obedience to the righteous requirements of Christ that would ensure they abide in Christ. Those who only pretend to abide in Christ, never have abided in him, though they may deceive others into thinking they do. Those who try to abide in Christ yet who know his requirements and disregard those, deceive themselves. Of course, by 'the law' is not meant the Mosaic Law Covenant, which is "the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us" and taken out of the way by nailing it to the cross (Colossians 2:14).
The significance of all of this seems to be that we can fool others, and we can fool ourselves, but we never can fool God and Christ. The word of God, and the Word of God must be known and obeyed by those who would not commit the sin of lawlessness.

I believe it's easy to see the connection between those who say, 'Lord, Lord' and yet do not do as Jesus taught. Jude addresses real faith in this light as does James in his letter.

Dear friends, although I was eager to write you about the salvation we
share, I found it necessary to write, appealing to you to contend for
the faith that was delivered to the saints once for all. For some
people, who were designated for this judgment long ago, have come in
by stealth; they are ungodly, turning the grace of our God into
sensuality and denying Jesus Christ, our only Master and Lord. (Jude
1:3,4)


But someone will say, “You have faith, and I have works.” Show me your
faith without works, and I will show you faith by my works. You
believe that God is one. Good! Even the demons believe—and they
shudder.
Senseless person! Are you willing to learn that faith without works is
useless? Wasn’t Abraham our father justified by works in offering
Isaac his son on the altar? You see that faith was active together
with his works, and by works, faith was made complete, and the
Scripture was fulfilled that says, Abraham believed God, and it was
credited to him as righteousness, and he was called God’s friend.
(James 2:18-23)

1 John also intricately shows what real faith is in John's explanation throughout his writing on the subject of what it means to believe into Jesus.
John then illustrated the very opposite of lawlessness here:

Everyone who believes that Jesus is the Christ has been born of God,
and everyone who loves the Father also loves the one born of him. This
is how we know that we love God’s children: when we love God and obey
his commands. For this is what love for God is: to keep his commands.
And his commands are not a burden, because everyone who has been born
of God conquers the world. This is the victory that has conquered the
world: our faith. (1 John 1:1-4)

A general search of Biblegateway shows some helpful verses:
BibleGateway word search;  But, digging even deeper into the Greek we can find the following verses and usage helpful:
Sin is lawlessness:
1 John 3:4
Jesus equates lawlessness to love growing cold spiritually:
Matthew 24:12
The meaning beneath the word lawlessness is literally "not law":

Greek meaning of lawlessness
Another place to seek definitions
of lawlessness
Strong's on the word lawlessness

This word lawlessness is used within an explanation of justice and lawlessness by historian Herodotus:
historian Herodotus usage

Answer
The “faith-alone” principle will not provide salvation without good works because Paul says:

“And now faith, hope, and love, these three things remain; but the
greatest of these is love” (1 Cor 13:13).

Love means good works.
So, 'faith alone and no works' is advocating lawlessness and it is compared to a house built on sand.
Explanation
There is a prophecy in the Old Testament about the Messiah:

“Jehovah is delighted for His righteousness' sake; He will magnify
the Law and make it honorable” (Isa 42:21).

This is what Jesus as the Messiah did in the Sermon on the Mount.

“You have heard that it was said to the ancients: "Do not commit
adultery. But I say to you, Everyone looking at a woman to lust after
her has already committed adultery with her in his heart” (Mat
5:27-28).

So, the Messiah magnified and tightened the Law instead of nailing it on the cross and abolishing it.
That is why Jesus stated clearly:

“Do not think that I came to annul the Law or the Prophets; I did not
come to annul, but to fulfill. Truly I say to you, Until the heaven
and the earth pass away, in no way shall one iota or one point pass
away from the Law until all comes to pass” (Mat 5:17-18).

Objection?:-
Some argue that, yes, Jesus fulfilled the Law by keeping it but after fulfilling, He abolished it.
This is a wrong argument because the same Greek word for fulfill is used by Jesus in John 15:11:

“These things have I spoken unto you, that my joy may be in you, and
that your joy may be fulfilled”.

Just as Jesus did not abolish their joy after fulfilling it (they had that “full” joy even afterwards), He did not abolish the Law after fulfilling it.
Apostle Paul also says the same thing:

“Then is the Law annulled through faith? Let it not be! But we
establish Law” (Rom 3:31).

Nobody can establish an already abolished Law.
But why, and why did Jesus say that He will not abolish the Law?

Because, “So indeed the Law is holy, and the commandment holy
and just (righteous) and good” (Rom 7:12).
“the Law is spiritual” (verse 14).

Jesus is not crazy to cancel something that is good, holy, righteous and spiritual. Besides, He said:

“It is the Spirit that gives life. The flesh does not profit,
nothing!” (John 6:63).

Since Jesus came to give abundant life (John 10:10) He will not abolish something that is “spiritual”.
Good Works for Salvation
No wonder when a young man asked about salvation, Jesus said:

“If you want to enter life, keep the commandments” (Mat 19:17).

The young man asked Him, “Which” commandments (verse 18) and Jesus pointed to the Ten Commandments (same verse).
First of all, we have seen that love is greater than faith.
But, what is the Scriptural definition of love?

“For this is the love of God, that we keep His commandments;
and His commandments are not heavy” (1 John 5:3).


“And this is love, that we should walk according to His
commandments” (2 John 1:6).

This is the Scriptural definition of Love. The secular definition is something else.
So love = obeying God by keeping His commandments.
True Love is Two-directional
Jesus Christ defines this bi-directional love:

“Teacher, which is the great commandment in the Law? And Jesus said to
him, "You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart, and
with all your soul, and with all your mind." This is the first and
great commandment.
“And the second is like it: "You shall love your neighbor as
yourself." On these two commandments all the Law and the Prophets
hang” (Mat 22:36-40).

The first command involves faith in God and Jesus Christ. The second command involves “good works” for others.
The fact is, Jesus was summarizing the Ten Commandments into two; love to God and love to fellow humans.
The first 4 of the Ten Commandments tell us how to love God and the second 6 instruct us how to love our neighbors.
This is beautifully explained by Apostle Paul:

“…..love one another. For the one loving the other has
fulfilled the Law. For, "Do not commit adultery," "do not murder," "do not steal," do not bear false witness, "do not lust," and if there
is any other commandment, in this word it is summed up, in the
words, "You shall love your neighbor as yourself (Rom 13:8-9)."

[Notice that it is not Jesus only who has fulfilled the Law but we also are required to fulfill the Law! Also notice that by loving the other we are fulfilling the Law. But we cannot hate the other just because we have fulfilled the Law by loving.]
Paul & the Ten Commandments

“For whether or not a man is circumcised means nothing; what matters
is to obey God's commandments (faith in God and love to man)” (1
Cor 7:19).


“For in Christ Jesus, neither circumcision nor uncircumcision has any
strength, but faith working through love” (Gal 5:6).


“Because of this, hearing of your faith in the Lord Jesus and
love toward all the saints” (Eph 1:15).


“that through faith Christ may dwell in your hearts, having been
rooted and founded in love” (Eph 3:17).


“hearing of your faith in Christ Jesus and the love toward all
the saints” (Col 1:4).


“but the end (telos=goal/purpose) of the commandment is love out
of a pure heart and a good conscience, and faith not pretended
(i.e., not faith alone)” (1 Tim 1:5).


“remembering without ceasing your work of faith and labor of
love” (1 Thes 1:3).

Conclusion
So, “working lawlessness” is disobedience to God by not keeping the commandments of love to God and love to fellow humans.
Jesus did not abolish this “good, righteous, holy, and spiritual” Law of love by nailing it on the cross.
‘Faith alone’ and ‘no works’ for salvation is in fact teaching “anomia=lawlessness”. Jesus compares that to building a house on sand. It will fail.
Annexure
Confusion on what the Works of Law is
Majority of Christians are confused over the term “the Works of Law”. They wrongly think this is keeping the Ten Commandments. They wrongly think Apostle Paul is teaching this.
Truth cannot be farther.
Works of Law is entirely different from the Ten Commandments.
Here is proof #1:
“For not the hearers of the Law are just with God, but the doers of the Law shall be justified” (Rom 2:13).
“Because by works of Law not one of all flesh will be justified before Him” (Rom 3:20).
Was an apostle of God and Jesus Christ so crazy to say contradictory verses in the same epistle in nearby places, if “works of Law” means keeping the Ten Commandments?
No. this cannot be. They cannot be the same.
Here is proof #2:
“but Israel following after a Law of righteousness did not arrive at a Law of righteousness? Why? Because it was not of faith, but as of works of Law” (Rom 9:31-32).
It cannot be plainer than this!
The very Apostle Paul contrasts “the Law of righteousness” on one hand and “the Works of Law” on the other.
So these are two different concepts which are in contrast. One is a spiritual ("righteousness") requirement and the other is a means; an invalid means after the Crucifixion of Christ!
Yes, works of Law means the animal sacrifices, the shadow of Christ’s sacrifice (Heb 10:1). The latter abolished and replaced the former.
Now the contradiction is cleared:
“For not the hearers of the Law (the spiritual Ten Commandments) are just with God, but the doers of the Law (the spiritual Ten Commandments) shall be justified” (Rom 2:13).
“Because by works of Law (animal sacrifices) not one of all flesh will be justified before Him” (Rom 3:20).
“but Israel following after a Law of righteousness (the spiritual Ten Commandments) did not arrive at a Law of righteousness? Why? Because it was not of faith, but as of works of Law (animal sacrifices). For they stumbled at the Stone-of-stumbling (the one and only sacrifice of Jesus Christ)” (Rom 9:31-32).

see Colossians 2:13,14 and Matthew 18 -- Jesus came to forgive. This debt we owe to the King of creation was cancelled and nailed to Jesus' cross. We need a Savior.
"So speak, and so act, as those who are about to be judged by the law of liberty (also see Romans 8:2-4), because judgment will be merciless to one who has shown no mercy; mercy triumphs over judgment. (James 2:12,13)
"In the same way you judge you will be judged." - Jesus

Yes, Jesus came to forgive our sins (Mat 9:6). Sin is the disobedience of God’s commandments (1 John 3:4). The debt is the debt of sins (Mat 6:12). The “law of liberty” is “the Royal law” which is “love your neighbor as yourself” (James 2:8) “because love will cover a multitude of sins” (1 Pet 4:8).  “We know that we have passed from death to life because we love the brothers. The one not loving the brother remains in death (judgment)” (1 Jn 3:14).

“By this, love has been perfected with us, that we have confidence in the day of judgment… There is no fear in love, but perfect love casts out fear” (1 Jn 4:17-18). “For this is the love of God, that we keep His commandments; and His commandments are not heavy” (1 Jn 5:3). And the first 4 of the Ten Commandments teach love towards God and the second 6 teach the love towards fellow humans.

@Nephish, Jesus' word [his ideology] is more exacting than Moses. Yet, "with God all things are possible". "For whom He foreknew, He also predestined to be conformed to the image of His Son, that He might be the firstborn among many brethren." Jesus said, "Without me you are able to do nothing." Yet Paul said, "I can do all things through Christ, who strengthens me." John said, "Yet, whoever keeps on keeping his word [ideology], in this person the love of God genuinely has been consummated [thoroughly matured, completed]." For our growth, see 1 John 2:13,14. We are forgiven. Romans 6:2.


Semantically, does ἀνομία ('lawlessness') imply a complete disregard for the law, or could it also refer to a superficial adherence …?

It could refer to either of those, or it could refer to many other things.
G458 - anomia - Strong's Greek Lexicon:

Outline of Biblical Usage

I. the condition of without law

I.1 because ignorant of it
I.2 because of violating it


II. contempt and violation of law, iniquity, wickedness


The critical idea is that one does not fully follow the law, regardless of the reason.
It doesn't matter whether it is through a lack of knowledge, carelessness, or deliberate action; the result is the same: lawlessness.
Either one does follow the law, or one doesn't; there is no in-between.
Jesus had the same message in Mark 7, where he described people that sincerely worshipped God, but didn't do it in the way God wants:

7 Howbeit in vain do they worship me, teaching for doctrines the commandments of men.
8 For laying aside the commandment of God, ye hold the tradition of men, as the washing of pots and cups: and many other such like things ye do.
9 And he said unto them, Full well ye reject the commandment of God, that ye may keep your own tradition.
…
13 Making the word of God of none effect through your tradition, which ye have delivered: and many such like things do ye.

Hence Jesus's "I never knew you. Go away from me, you lawbreakers!".

The Gospel emphasizes salvation through faith in Jesus Christ and the grace of God's forgiveness, rather than adherence to the law of Moses. As James 2:10 states: "For whoever keeps the whole law and yet stumbles at just one point is guilty of breaking all of it." (NIV) Is there anyone who can keep the entire law without fail?
Paul affirms in Ephesians 2:8-9, "8 For it is by grace you have been saved, through faith—and this is not from yourselves, it is the gift of God— 9 not by works, so that no one can boast. (NIV)" He further explains in Galatians 2:16 that "a person is not justified by the works of the law, but by faith in Jesus Christ. So we, too, have put our faith in Christ Jesus that we may be justified by faith in Christ and not by the works of the law, because by the works of the law no one will be justified."
To align with Gospel teachings, some Translations of Matthew 7:23 avoid the term "lawlessness" (Strong's 458), to prevent any association with "law". The KJV uses "iniquity" and the NIV uses "evildoers".
In Matthew 7:24-27, the parable of "The Wise and Foolish Builders", Jesus describes the righteous as those who hear His words and act on them. In contrast, evildoers hear but neglect His words, embodying the disobedience implied by Strong's 458.
It is essential to understand that Jesus does not emphasize works in this parable, He emphasizes the importance of His words, with works naturally following as a consequence of faith in Him.
Referring to the two scenarios OP questioned, whether one disregards His words or follows them outwardly without genuine faith, both are classified as "disobedience" and belong to the category of the foolish builders.

As a new Greek translator of the New Testament in modern Greek language, the translation of verses 21-27, i think, is as follows:
“Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven. 22 Many will say to me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name? Did we not cast out demons in your name? Did we not do many miracles in your name?’ 23 And then I will confess to them, ‘You always were strangers to me; depart from me, you workers of lawlessness.’”
24 Therefore everyone who hears these words of mine and does them will be like a conscientious man who built his house on the stone. 25 And the rain descended, and the floods came, and the winds blew, and beat on that house, and it did not fall, for it had been founded on the stone. 26 And everyone who hears these words of mine and does not do them will be like an unconscious man who built his house on the sand. 27 And the rain descended, and the floods came, and the winds blew, and beat on that house, and it fell; and its fall was great.”
Comments:
In short, God does not seek people who are characterized as talkative and chatty, nor does He like begging, but He seeks people who are willing to do His will. The believers, as described by the Lord, were not, in essence, executors of His will, but they offered an enthusiasm to their spectators and felt great, and had the reassurance that they were children of God, since they performed miracles, but this is not what God wanted. He himself said to them, confessing to them (in a free translation): you are strangers to me. And I think it is the most careful translation that reflects his meaning.
Now, as a reference to the construction of the house, here, perhaps, although more likely, it relates to a building that, not only its foundation is made of stone, but also its entire structure. This man is likened to conscientious, in the sense that he understands what he hears/reads, and understands their importance and carries them out. And the other type, who is likened to unconscious, i.e. the one who hears/reads, but does not consider their importance, and does not reach the point of carrying them out. His house is built on a foundation of sand, as is all the rest of his building. This is the meaning, I believe, of the phrase: "ἐπὶ τὴν πέτραν", and: "ἐπὶ τὴν ἄμμον".

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

how can I substantiate a translation or commentary of mine that is not supported by most, if not all, translations that exist? Therefore, just because I draw a conclusion of my own, does not mean that it is a true formulation of these verses. It is merely a conclusion.

If Jesus wanted to say upon the rock, as a basis, he would probably say, "ἐπὶ τῇ πέτρᾳ" using dative case, which translates "upon the rock". But "ἐπὶ τὴν πέτραν" is probably translated, as building using stone. And this is also substantiated by the logic that if one were building a house on a rock and using as raw material, clay bricks of soil clay, if the storms came, would it not fall? And conversely, if one were to build a house on sand, what might happen would be that the house would be flooded underneath and the house would be swept away from its base, but the whole house would not fall apart and the fall would not be great, as Jesus said. And by saying "ἐπὶ τὴν ἄμμον," I think he does not necessarily mean the sand of the desert; but in general the pure soil, which may be in a terrestrial form (dense). For the word "ἄμμος," has various meanings. Two of these are the common sand of the beach and rivers/lakes, or of the desert; and the other meaning is such as that soil used for racing, which is smooth and suitable for that use.
